# Best practices to handle Web API status codes

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, restsharp, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web API project done with .NETCore.

My web API receives a request from another Service A, with the information I have I need to do some conversion on the data and send it to another Service B.

I am expecting that Service B send back some response: like OK or NOK. As the number of codes I can get back from Service B are so much. I would like to know which is the best practices to handle those codes?

As you will see in my code, I get the status code in this way:

```
var status = (int)response.StatusCode;
```

And the I have some if to handle this. Looking at my code it looks like a very poor status code Handling but at moment it is the best I can do. I am kindly asking suggestions to improve this.

I am using RestSharp.
Following my code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Produces("application/json", Type = typeof(MyModel))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]MyModel myModel)
    {
         try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var response = (RestResponse) await _restHelper.GetResponse("ServiceB:url", myModel);

            if (response != null)
            {
                var status = (int)response.StatusCode;

                //2xx status OK
                if (status >= 200 && status < 300)
                {
                    return Ok(response.Content);
                }

                //Catch all status code
                return StatusCode(status, response.Content);
            }

            //If for some reason, I don't get any response from ServiceB
            return NotFound("No response from ServiceB");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("POST_ERROR", "ServiceB-relay/Post UNEXPECTED ERROR", ex.Message);
            return StatusCode(500, "Server error, not able to process your request");
        }
    }
```

and this is my restHelper

```
    public class RestHelper: IRestHelper
    {
        private readonly IConfigurationRoot _config;

        public RestHelper(IConfigurationRoot config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public async Task<IRestResponse> GetResponse(string configKey, object dtoObject)
        {
            //Get the URL from the config.json
            var url = _config[configKey];

            //Create rest client and rest request
            var restClient = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest {Timeout = 30000, Method = Method.POST};

            //Add header
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            //convert the dto object to json
            var jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtoObject.ToString(), Formatting.Indented);
            request.AddParameter("application/json", jsonObject, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();

            //Execute async
            restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, r => taskCompletion.SetResult(r));

            //await the task to finish
            var response = (RestResponse) await taskCompletion.Task;

            return response;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Primarily opinion based question. In my opinion I see no issue with how you are currently returning status codes. If however there are no errors or problems with the code then this becomes a [codereview.SE]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, can you please put your response in the main thread?

Comment: It's fine as it is, but you shouldn't ever return 500 from a Rest service. That being said, the exception can be moved inside the rest client

Comment: Thanks, moved the try catch inside my RestHelper. If I can't return 500, which one should I return when the code goes in the catch block of the try?

Comment: I normally do an explicit check for 404 situation or catch `ItemNotFound` type exceptions thrown by services and return `NotFound`